# ORM ManyToOne Unidirectional fetchAll Object array does not render in phtml Zend Framework 3

Tags: orm, zend-framework3

The application has built in ZF3. I have to entity with ManyToOne relationship using ORM. The issue is when i render through controller and and if fetch data via index it gives okay result but when i assign that to view and trying to render at phtml it throws an error/

```
/**
 * Subscriptions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="subscriptions", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="CUST_ID", columns={"customer_id"}),@ORM\Index(name="SUB_TYPE_ID", columns={"subscription_type_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Subscriptions
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\SubscriptionType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SubscriptionType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subscription_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $subscriptionType;

    //set
    public function setSubscriptionType(\Application\Entity\SubscriptionType $subscriptionType = null)
    {
        $this->subscriptionType = $subscriptionType;

        return $this;
    }

    //get
     public function getSubscriptionType(){
        return $this->subscriptionType;
    }

   //other setter and getter....
}
```

Another Class

```
/**
 * SubscriptionType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="subscription_type")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SubscriptionType
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * Get id
     *enter code here
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return SubscriptionType
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now at controller i have wrote...

//some initiations

```
class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{

 //other initiations including __construct....

public function usersubscriptionsAction(){
   $this->subscriptions = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Subscriptions::class)->findAll();

   /*
   foreach($this->subscriptions as $subscription){
      //if i am checking with this it gives proper output
      echo $subscription->getSubscriptionType()->getDescription();
       die();
     }
   */
  return new ViewModel(
                array(
                    "subscriptions" => $this->subscriptions
                )
         );
}

}
```

///i have phtml file

```
<?php foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription): ?>
  //below line throwing an error
  <?php echo $subscription->getSubscriptionType()->getDescription(); ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

when i run it throw an erro message
Call to a member function getDescription() on null

Comment: Try to put "die()" outside the foreach block. You are only outputing the 1st description.

Comment: Thanks @JannesBotis i figured it out there was one of record throwing NULL value in subscriptions table in column subscription_type_id which is FK of subscriptionsType table. The value had been set to that db table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the relation mapping incorrect. Corrected the property annotation below:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\SubscriptionType
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SubscriptionType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subscription_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $subscriptionType;
```

You had

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\SubscriptionType
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SubscriptionType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subscription_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $subscriptionType;
```

The `@ORM\JoinColumns` is used for when you have a join with multiple columns, please [see the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumns). Though, the most common usage of `JoinColumns` is for a [`JoinTable`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#jointable).